# How to count and remove element at the same time in the list in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I have two procedures, one for counting an element in the list and the other one for removing the same element from the same list. What should I do for counting and removing at the same time? I am trying it for long time but nothing is working. I work with this list: (list 1 2 3 2 1 2 3), finally it should be like: ((1 . 2) (2 . 3) (3 . 2)). The first number of pair is an element and second number of pair is sum of first pair's number from all list.
My try: 
1) it works only with counting and result is: ((1 . 2) (2 . 3) (3 . 2) (2 . 2) (1 . 1) (2 . 1) (3 . 1))
2) it works only with removing and result is: ((1 . 2) 2 3 2 2 3)

Where is the problem?

This is for counting:

```
(define count-occurrences
  (lambda (x ls)
    (cond
      [(memq x ls) =>
       (lambda (ls)
         (+ (count-occurrences x (cdr ls)) 1))]
      [else 0])))
```

(count-occurrences '2 (list 1 2 3 2 1 2 3)) -> 3

This is for removing:

```
(define (remove-el p s)
  (cond ((null? s) '())
        ((equal? p (car s)) (remove-el p (cdr s)))
        (else (cons (car s) (remove-el p (cdr s))))))
```

(remove-el '2 (list 1 2 3 2 1 2 3))  -> (1 3 1 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return the count and the removed list at once. I call this routine
count-remove. (Pardon to all schemers for not idiomatic or efficient style)

```
(define (count-remove ls x)
  (letrec ([loop (lambda (count l removed)
                   (cond
                     [(eq? l '()) (list count removed)]
                     [(eq? (car l) x) (loop (+ 1 count) (cdr l) removed)]
                     [else (loop count (cdr l) (cons (car l) removed))]))])
    (loop 0 ls '())))

(define (count-map ls)
  (cond
    [(eq? ls '()) '()]
    [else
       (letrec ([elem (car ls)]
                [cr (count-remove ls elem)])
         (cons (cons elem (car cr)) (count-map (cadr cr))))]))
```

Here is some usage:

`(count-map '(1 1 2 3 2))

((1 . 2) (2 . 2) (3 . 1))`

Comment: Thank you. It is a litle bit complicated to understand for me because I am just beginner, but it is working. I should study Scheme more harder.